# WP7 Max width textbox and position to set from right

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have this code:

```
<controls:PivotItem Header="Hledat">
    <Canvas Margin="0">
        <TextBox  Name="SearchTxb"  Height="72" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        <Button Name="SearchBtn" Margin="0,74,100,0" Width="200" Height="72" Click="SearchBtn_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">Hledat</Button>
    </Canvas>
</controls:PivotItem>
```

and I want to support Portrait and Landscape. This should be pivotitem for search. I want to textbox to change width to full size of phone screen and I want to button set position to f.e. 20 from right side. What should I add to code? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<controls:PivotItem Header="Hledat">
    <Grid Margin="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinition>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="0"  Name="SearchTxb"  Height="72" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Name="SearchBtn" Margin="0,74,100,0" Width="200" Height="72" Click="SearchBtn_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">Hledat</Button>
    </Grid>
</controls:PivotItem>
```

Comment: With Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  in textbox it was exactly what I was looking for, thanks